# Comparing and Count Values from 2 (or More) Different Pandas Dataframes Based on Certain Conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count, compare

Assuming that I have monthly datasets showing like these:

`df1`

| company | date | act_call | act_visit | po |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2022-10-01 | Yes | No | No |
| B | 2022-10-01 | Yes | No | Yes |
| C | 2022-10-01 | No | No | No |
| B | 2022-10-02 | No | Yes | No |
| A | 2022-10-02 | No | Yes | Yes |

`df2`

| company | date | act_call | act_visit | po |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| D | 2022-11-01 | Yes | No | No |
| B | 2022-11-01 | Yes | No | Yes |
| C | 2022-11-01 | Yes | Yes | No |
| D | 2022-11-02 | No | Yes | No |
| A | 2022-11-02 | No | Yes | Yes |

I want to compare the two dataframes and count several conditions:

1. the number of company that exists in both dataframes.
2. the number of company that exists in both dataframes that has at least one `act_call` as 'Yes' and `act_visit` as 'Yes' in `df2`, but has `po` as 'No' in `df1`.

For the 1st condition, I've tried using `pandas.Dataframe.sum()` and `pandas.Dataframe.count_values()` but they didn't give the results that I want.

For the 2nd condition, I tried using this code:

`(((df1[['act_calling', 'act_visit']].eq('yes'))&(df2['po'].eq('no'))).groupby(df2['company_name']).any().all(axis = 1).sum())`

but, I'm not sure that the code above will only count the company that exists in both dataframes.

**The expected output is this:**

1. 3, (A, B, C)
2. 1, (C)

I'm open to any suggestions. Thank u in advance!

Answer (score 0):

### companies that exists in both dfs

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, on="company", how="inner")['company'].unique()
Out[40]: array(['A', 'B', 'C'], dtype=object)
len(pd.merge(df1, df2, on="company", how="inner")['company'].unique())
Out[41]: 3
```

### 2nd part

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on="company", how="inner")
df3[(df3.act_call_y == 'Yes') & (df3.act_visit_y == 'Yes') & (df3.po_x=='No')]
Out[54]: 
  company      date_x act_call_x act_visit_x po_x      date_y act_call_y act_visit_y po_y
4       C  01/10/2022         No          No   No  2022-11-01        Yes         Yes   No

len(df3[(df3.act_call_y == 'Yes') & (df3.act_visit_y == 'Yes') & (df3.po_x=='No')])
Out[56]: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

##### the number of company that exists in both dataframes.

```
set(df1['company']).intersection(df2['company'])
# {'A', 'B', 'C'}

len(set(df1['company']).intersection(df2['company']))
# 3
```

##### the number of company that exists in both dataframes that has at least one `act_call` as 'Yes' and `act_visit` as 'Yes' in `df2`, but has `po` as 'No' in `df1`.

```
s1 = df1['po'].eq('No').groupby(df1['company']).any()

d2 = {'act_call': 'Yes', 'act_visit': 'Yes'}
s2 = df2[list(d2)].eq(d2).groupby(df2['company']).any().all(axis=1)

s = (s1&s2)
s = set(s[s].index)
# {'C'}

len(s)
# 1
```

Answer (score 0):

## To See The Companies That Are In Both Data Frames

1st part

combined_dataframe1=df1[df2['company'].isin(df1['company'])]

combined_dataframe1['company']

2nd part

## To see the company that satisfies your conditions

combined_dataframe2=df2[df2['company'].isin(df1['company'])]

joined_dataframe=pd.merge(combined_dataframe1,combined_dataframe2, on='company',how='outer')

## As per your condition

final_dataframe=joined_dataframe[joined_dataframe.columns][joined_dataframe['po_x']=='n0'}[joined_dataframe['act_call_yes']=='yes'][joined_dataframe['act_visit_y']=='yes']
print(final_dataframe)

Comment: Your answer looks good, but could benefit from some formatting improvements. Using boldface instead of headers as well as formatting code as code would really benefit readers.